# how to redirect an url on symfony 6

Tags: php, symfony6

I want to display my admin page, I got this error:

> Cannot autowire service "App\Controller\Admin\DashboardController": argument "$adminUrlGenerator" of method "__construct()" has type "App\Controller\Admin\AdminUrlGeneretor" but this class was not found.

This is my code:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin

use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Dashboard;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\MenuItem;

use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractDashboardController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class DashboardController extends AbstractDashboardController
{
    
    public function __construct(
       
    private AdminUrlGeneretor $adminUrlGenerator
    
    ){
     }
    #[Route('/admin', name: 'admin')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        $url= $this->adminUrlGenerator
            ->setController(ProductCrudController::class)
            ->generateUrl();
    
        return $this->redirect($url);
    }
    
    public function configureDashboard(): Dashboard
    {
        return Dashboard::new()
            ->setTitle('Bonito');
    }
    
    public function configureMenuItems(): iterable
    {
        yield MenuItem::linkToDashboard('Dashboard', 'fa fa-home');
        // yield MenuItem::linkToCrud('The Label', 'fas fa-list', EntityClass::class);
    }
}
```

I tried to fixed it, but getting error. I need help please.

Answer (score 0):

You have an obvious typo:  AdminUrlGeneretor

The class you are actually trying to reference and use is:

```
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Router\AdminUrlGenerator;
```

Note the correct spelling for your constructor parameter should be:

```
private AdminUrlGenerator $adminUrlGenerator
```